# Java equal too, but with a buffer

Tags: java, swing

I have made a simple game and I have a simple way to detect when I have collected a coin but it is very hard to match its position exactly.

```
public class Token {
    private String name;
    int x;
    int y;
    private BufferedImage image;
    public Token (String nameIn, int xIn, int yIn, BufferedImage imageIn)
    {   
        name = nameIn;
        x = xIn;
        y = yIn;
        image = imageIn;
    }

    public boolean collected(Hero frylark) {
        if (frylark.getX() == x && frylark.getY() == y) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way i can have a buffer of say 10 pixels instead of
matching the position of the coin exactly.

Answer (score 3):

A distance between two points in a two-dimensional field is the sum of the squares of the differences between their corresponding coordinates:

```
public boolean collected(Hero frylark) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(frylark.getX() - x , 2) + 
                     Math.pow(frylark.getY() - y , 2)
                    ) <= 10.0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on Mureinik's answer, you can do this faster by not use Math.pow nor Math.sqrt.

```
double dx = frylark.getX() - x;
double dy = frylark.getY() - y;
return dx*dx + dy*dy <= 10.0*10.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have made a simple game and I have a simple way to detect when I have collected a coin but it is very hard to match its position exactly.

I will propose a slightly different approach for you. If you attempt to detect collision by using only the x and y coordinates, it is very hard to detect collision since you need both pixels to hit at the same spot.

This problem arises especially when you try to check collision for images of different sizes:

**Exmaple:**

[image] [image]

With your current implementation, in order for the `Game Character` to hit the `coin`, the ***red pixel*** (top left hand corner) has to collide, and you end up needed to add a buffer for images of different sizes to check for collision.

---

I will advise returning a bounding box for each object and check weather their bounding boxes intersects:

```
public boolean collected(Hero h){
    Rectangle heroBox = new Rectangle (h.getX(), h.getY(), h.getWidth(), h.getHeight());
    Rectangle coinBox = new Rectangle (x, y, width, height);
    return(coinBox.intersects(heroBox));
}
```

You will need the width and height (which is usually the width and height of your images) of your objects for creating the bounding box.

**Advantage:**

- You no longer have to check the size of each image and set the buffer for them individually.

---

> Is there any way i can have a buffer of say 10 pixels instead of
>    matching the position of the coin exactly.

**Adding a buffer:**

If you still want a buffer, say 10 pixel. We can still apply it in this implementation:

```
public boolean collected(Hero h, int buffer){
    Rectangle heroBox = new Rectangle (h.getX(), h.getY(), h.getWidth() + buffer, h.getHeight() + buffer);
    Rectangle coinBox = new Rectangle (x, y, width + buffer , height + buffer);
    return(coinBox.intersects(heroBox));
}
```

By adding the given buffer, we enlarge the area of the bounding boxes, hence making it more sensitive. You can always tweak from my example to add the buffer on one of the objects, both objects, or on only the width or the height of either objects.